# List of shared pointers

Tags: list, shared-ptr, lifetime

I have a shared pointer to the result of some calculation as follows:

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<myResult>> ResultList;
for (int i= 0; i < upperBound; i++)
{
    DoCalculation();
    std::shared_ptr<myResult> Res;
    Res = DoCalculation->GetOutput();
    ResultList.push_back(Res);
}
```

In debug mode I can see that at each iteration `Res` is updated, though all values in `ResultList` are equal to the last iteration's `Res` pushed to `ResultList`. How can I keep the result of calculation in the list using `Res`?

Comment: can you just do `ResultList.push_back(DoCalculation->GetOutput());`

Comment: "all values in ResultList are equal to the last iteration's Res pushed to ResultList" - Do you mean that each value is equal to the value from the previous iteration or that all values are equal to the last single value?

Comment: If Res is properly being set, then the way you're pushing it into the list is correct. How are you checking the values in ResultList?